# sub-entity schema implementation

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony, formbuilder

I want to implement a system of category and their associated options in Symfony 2.

So a Category (example: car, Home) have categoryOption (example: date, color, size, etc…).

Moreover, the Category entities have many to one relationship with the advert entity. I mean an Advert can have only one Category but infinite Advert can be attached to a Category.
So, at the end, I want to be able to make a dynamic form like that:

[image]

If I select a category (ex: caravanning), all of the attached subcategory will appear like that:

[image]

And allow the user to select or enter the desired information.

I already have implemented the Category and Advert entity but I don’t know what schema to use for the options and how to generate the form.
 Do I have to create a new categoryOption entity and make a relationship with Advert and Category or use another way?

Of course, the categoryOption attached to the advert can be edited by the user.

Comment: This is an *entity-attribute-value* model. `Category` is the entity, `CategoryOption` the attribute and e.g. `CategoryOptionValue` the value. Three different tables, where `CategoryOptionValue` has foreign keys to the former two. EAV is seen as an anti pattern, but sometimes it's inevitable, or the best of all "eavils". By the way, I assume that `subcategory` and `CategoryOption` are the same?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, indeed it's the same. I edited the question. But in your example how to implement the fact that a Category Entity can have more than one `CategoryOption` ? Can you show me the declaration of the three entity for you idea ? And What about the `Advert `=>How can i have an Advert with category = Car and `CategoryOption` ="color"=red and another one with color = "blue" ?